# Add launchpad quick link

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

For the comments we have lots of links, such as `[se]` and `[ubuntu.se]`.

Here is a list of requested redirects, from me and the comments:

`[launchpad]` goes to `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu` and shows as [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu)

`[launchpad#bugnum]` goes to `https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugnum` and shows as [Bug #bugnum](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugnum)

`[forums]` goes to `http://ubuntuforums.org/` and sows as [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org)

`[discourse]` goes to `http://discourse.ubuntu.com` and shows as [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.Ubuntu.com)

`[paste]` or `[pastebinit]` goes to `http://paste.ubuntu.com` and shows as [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com)

`[install-d]` goes to `http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop` and shows as [Install Ubuntu Desktop](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

`[install-s]` goes to `http://ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server` and shows as [Install Ubuntu Server](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

`ppa:peterlevi/ppa` goes to `https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi` and shows as [ppa:peterlevi/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi)

Comment: Example: [ubuntu.se] and [se] and [so], typed as `[ubuntu.se] and [se] and [so]`

Comment: I didn't even know these things existed... (n.b. it would be great ot have thing that could automatically link to PPAs to their page on launchpad)

Comment: So it would detect `ppa:peterlevi/ppa` and make it link to `https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi`?

Comment: "[launchpad] is cool" would show as "[launchpad](http://launchpad.net) is cool" without having to type the (http://launchpad.net) part

Comment: It's possible, but the SE developers would have to implement it. I can see them doing a few special ones for us, but not too many. Just my opinion.

Comment: I could have sworn that http://pad.lv was available as a shortener for linking to Launchpad that requires no special action for use.  For example, `http://pad.lv/ppa/skellat/tests` gives the same expanded output as `ppa:skellat/tests`.

Comment: @Stephen Still longer to type by guite a bit...

Comment: I think `[download]`, `[install]` and `[paste]` are a bit of an overkill. How much do those get used comments **for that exact meaning**? And what would happen if someone wrote something like the following: `[download](http://some.link/to/download/some/application/)` or if that gets taken care of, missing something in the markup like: `[download]http://some.link/to/download/some/application/)` would make the download point to Ubuntu which makes it worse. My point is that those are too generic and can mean a lot of things to be used as quick links.

Comment: It could be changed but i do use paste a lot

Comment: Why should [download] go to the _desktop_ version?

Comment: @Cijco Because most people are asking about it. Remember you could go to  server with the actual link. Very few questions are actually asking how to install it, the questions are post install.